# Animating single line chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am new to Google Line Chart. The chart which I try to draw is drawn properly but I want to animate it. I tried using animation section in code but seems it does not work at all on single line chart.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Test');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Test 2');

  data.addRows([
    [1, 37.8],
    [2, 30.9],
    [3, 25.4],
    [4, 11.7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    animation: {
      duration: 1000,
      startup: true, //This is the new option
      easing: 'out',
    },
    aggregationTarget: 'category',
    chart: {
      title: 'Test 1',
      subtitle: 'Test 2'
    },
    width: '98%',
    height: 300,
    axes: {
      x: {
        0: {
          side: 'top'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

animation isn't supported on *Material* charts
in fact, there are several options *Material* charts do not support

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

---

*Material* charts --> `google.charts.Line` -- `packages: ['line']`

*Core* charts --> `google.visualization.LineChart` -- `packages: ['corechart']`

---

using a *Core* chart with the following option will display *similar* to *Material*

```
theme: 'material'
```